# Running Excel Add-ins in Python: Performance?

Tags: python, excel, performance

Apologies if this is a silly question, but I don't know the answer so here it goes...If an Excel add-in is called from Python, is there any performance gain in that function versus just calculating the function in Excel?

A little background for why I'm asking:

I use a third party Excel add-in for some quant calculations, but I have a huge spreadsheet that really lags when making these calculations all at once. I was hoping that if I were able to call these Excel add-in functions from Python, it might pick up some efficiency (somehow?). I've moved over some spreadsheets and they do seem a bit faster than if they're run Excel, but I'm not sure if it's just a coincidence.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you've moved to python from Excel then is there a reason you can't go all the way and switch to [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/tutorials.html) and drop the excel dependency altogether?

Comment: Can you see what the 3rd party add-ins are actually doing / is it a standard procedure in your industry? Pandas was developed in that industry too so it's possible it's supported off-the-bat.

Comment: Would love to get away from Excel entirely, but unfortunately, I can't see behind the curtain of the add-ins to be able to reproduce it - QuantLib is probably the closest library to what I need, but it's pretty cryptic to say the least without a ton of documentation.